# Browser seems to ignore caching headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

When an image is requested to my ASP.NET application, my C# code responds with the binary data in addition to the following headers (as capture in Fiddler):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Expires: Fri, 06 Sep 2013 21:43:21 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Sep 2013 22:21:27 GMT
ETag: "0x8D0770B10F6F56D"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 06 Sep 2013 21:13:23 GMT
Content-Length: 39007
```

My expectation is that the browser will cache this image until at least 21:43 GMT (which is 30 minutes from now) but that's not what happens. When I press F5, my browser sends another request for the image to my ASP.NET application.

What is missing from my headers to ensure the file is properly cached?

Comment: What happens if you open your browser view the page, close it then reopen the page without doing an explicit refresh ?

Comment: @Francis a new request is sent. I tried with IE, Chrome and even Firefox and they all behave the same: they send a new request every single time I press F5.